# C# tutorial to write gadgets

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-desktop-gadgets

How can I write gadgets for the Windows 7 desktop using C# and Visual Studio 2008? I'm looking for tutorials and resources on that topic.

Comment: Think this should be community wiki

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Why wiki? Straightforward question.

Comment: google.com and microsoft.com are fairly good indicators of if you have a working internet connection or not. In 2007, Google had a total downtime of 7 minutes and Microsoft clocked in 13 minutes.

Comment: George, you mean Gadgets for Vista and Windows 7?

Comment: By any chance did the 7 and 13 minutes overlap?

Comment: I want to write Gadgets for Vista, if the same code could work for Windows 7 or later version, it will be great! Any recommendations?

Comment: @ThePower - I don't think so. I can't find any mention of the two overlapping.

Comment: Hello gurus, let us come back to my original quesiton, any turorials about how to develop gadgets for recommendation?

Comment: @ThePower, I do not find discussion about how to develop gadgets from the wiki link you recommended. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Authoring Sidebar Gadgets in C#](http://web.archive.org/web/20101218165848/http://nikhilk.net/SidebarGadgets.aspx).

C# is not the only option. This [detailed tutorial](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/463.aspx) explains how to develop gadgets without C#. (Orginally gadgets were authored in a mix of XML, HTML, CSS, and some IE scripting language.)

[How to get started with Windows 7 gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902818/how-to-get-started-with-windows-7-gadgets) is a related Stack Overflow question that may also provide additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it myself, but this might help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/RunVistaGadget2.aspx

Comment: Hi, this is not a tutorial about how to write gadgets, but how to write a plug-in for VSTS to develop gadgets. Any turorials about how to develop gadgets for recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

Gadget-creation, calling your .NET-code via Interop:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/GadgetInterop.aspx

nice & powerful with good example

Comment: Also:

Visual-Studio Solution-Example for a Silverlight-Gadget:
http://www.lazarciuc.ro/ioan/2008/08/02/creating-a-vista-sidebar-gadget-using-microsoft-silverlight/

very tricky, but enables you to design your gadget with silverlight.