# how to develop an active desktop application in c#

Tags: c#, desktop, windows-desktop-gadgets

i want to develop a nice thing that will be on the desktop (like an active desktop) something like this:

http://www.tinnes.org.uk/desktopcalendar/about.htm

or this:

http://www.xemico.com/adc/screenshots.html

**Edit:**
That gadget should be common for XP,Vista, Windows 7 and that gadget size should be adjustable

Comment: Loved this quote from the first link: "Important dates such as birthdays, dentist appointments or deadlines won’t sneak up on you as you’ll be alerted days before they happen." Wow, this "calendar" idea sounds very innovative!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vista or seven you likely want develop a desktop gadget.

Look at this answer for some hints: [C# tutorial to write gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171588/c-tutorial-to-write-gadgets)