# Convert a WinForms Application to a Windows Desktop Gadget

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have created a C# WinForms application and now I'd like to know if there is a way to somehow convert it so I could use it as desktop gadget.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find a satisfying answer. I am not a very skilled programmer so please try to explain me the solution as if explaining it to dummy.

Comment: With `Desktop Widget` you mean those objects I can put on dekstop from Windows Vista on?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. Like calendar, clock, CPU performance gauge etc.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Desktop gadgets?

This question ""[C# tutorial to write gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171588/c-sharp-tutorial-to-write-gadgets)" has details about how to write desktop gadgets using c#. I think you can figure out the next step :)