# desktop widgets for windows xp on .net

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone recommend good libraries/components/sdk/tutorials for writing desktop widgets for os Windows XP and higher on C# .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Vista; checkout [Windows Sidebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965850%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The Windows Sidebar is a lockable panel on the Windows Vista desktop, similar to the Windows Taskbar, that is able to host and manage mini-applications known as "gadgets".

Here is [Windows Sidebar Reference Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486366%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article: [Authoring sidebar gadgets in C# .NET](http://www.nikhilk.net/SidebarGadgets.aspx)

Also, see this Stack Overflow question, [Getting started with Windows 7 gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902818/how-to-get-started-with-windows-7-gadgets).